# Need jquery to animate immediately on page load instead of on click

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm using this code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Arrow_Down_Mobile , #Arrow_Down_Mobile_other").click(function() {
      doBounce($(this), 10, '10px', 300);
    });


    function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
      for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element.animate({
          marginTop: '-=' + distance
        }, speed).animate({
          marginTop: '+=' + distance
        }, speed);
      }
    }

});
```

It works perfectly fine, however I'm trying to change the behavior from `click()` so that it can start playing immediately once the page loads.

I've tried `ready`, `live()`, `trigger()`, `on()`, `load()` etc. yet none of them play the animation right away so I'm running out of ideas here as to how to get this animation to work other than by clicking on it.

Comment: Just call `deBounce()` directly within document.ready. Note there will *always* be a slight delay before that fires as the DOM needs to load first. There is nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   doBounce($("#Arrow_Down_Mobile , #Arrow_Down_Mobile_other"), 10, '10px', 300)
});
```

We can't see your attempt to implement the [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method, but make sure you're calling it on the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object.